# Cast object to int doesn't work

Tags: c#, casting

I have FormView and bind to **CommandArgument** Property Id of record:

```
CommandArguman='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
```

but in server side in ItemCommand handler this doesn't work:

```
int id = e.CommandArgument;
```

and get Error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

but this work:

```
int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Return type of  **e.CommandArgument** is Object but why I cant Cast Object to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant cast and `object` to `int` without specific cast such as `(int)e.CommandArgument` and you can't do that because the object is a string.

you can do

```
int id = int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
```

if `e.CommandArgument` is a `string`, but you won't benefit it anymore then your code

in fact i would leave your code as it is, because it won't be thrown if the object is null or not a string. you can also use safe word `as` for the cast, but again you won't benefit from it.

for further learning search "casting" or read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)